# Comparing lengths of three segments in triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, triangles

I would like to ask if someone could help me with solving the following task.

The middle triangle is KLM (hatched). Prove that $|AK| = |KL| = 3|LB_1|$.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You already asked this question twice, receiving two fine answers and a very informative link. Please avoid asking again!

Comment: Nope, I don't know the prove to this property.

Comment: See here (figure at middle of page) for a very easy graphical proof: https://web.archive.org/web/20060427055758/http://www.randi.org/jr/02-09-2001.html